# How to fill jobjectArray with BSTR?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I need to fill jobjectArray (actually jstring array on java side) with BSTRs (C++ side). I am unable to convert BSTR to jobject.
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing from the documentation and the jni.h file:

```
jstring theJavaString = jnienv->NewString(bstr, SysStringLen(bstr));
jnienv->SetObjectArrayElement(theArray, i, theJavaString);
```

NewString accepts Unicode characters (which the BSTR is already) and the string length. (I thought there was a macro for BSTR length that just evaluated `bstr[-1]` that you could use instead of the API call but I can't find it.)

Comment: Thanks Rup for reply, that was helpful.